# Google Admob increased my project size so much

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I want to use Admob in my Swift project so I installed `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'` into my Pod file. My project size was about 5.5 MB to begin with. When I installed Google SDK, the Project size increased to 146.2 MB. I just want to use Admob not other Google services in my project.

### My questions

- Are there any better ways to add the package?
- When I push my app to AppStore the size will be decreased?
- Will the total size of my project change when I push to AppStore?

### Some helpful info

When I run the project on my mobile phone my app's size is 55.6 MB.

Comment: try archive project to .ipa and check size

Comment: I don't have a developer account so I can't

Comment: your project size and app size will be very different

Comment: Google pod increased the size about 140 MB. will be decrease? and how much?

Comment: You will know you .ipa file size only when you create it

Comment: so for creating .ipa I need a developer account. Thank you